# do_install error for custom bitbake recipe

Tags: autotools, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build simple hello world using bitbake recipe for learning but I receive error "no rule to make target 'install'" always. I am using following bitbake recipe

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
DEPENDS = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

MY_FILES = "/usr/share/cFile/testworld.tar.gz"
S = "${WORKDIR}/testworld"
inherit autotools
```

My testworld folder consist of test.c, configure.ac and Makefile.am. The configure.ac content is following:

```
AC_INIT([Tutorial Program], 1.0)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_INSTALL
AC_PROG_MAKE_SET

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and Makefile.am content is following

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = tut_prog         
tut_prog_SOURCES = test.c
```

Comment: You need to create an own layer and add your files via the variable `SRC_URI`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to my problem I only needed to change one line in my bitbake recipe instead of this

```
MY_FILES = "/usr/share/cFile/testworld.tar.gz"
```

I need to use this

```
SRC_URI = "file:///usr/share/cFile/testworld.tar.gz"
```